# Using Thymeleaf with Tiles2 and Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm trying to use [Thymeleaf integration with Apache Tiles 2.x](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-tiles2). They have a guide how to make it work so I followed it, but now I'm stuck.

Basically this integration allows using both JSPs and Thymeleaf templates and according to the guide, you should be able to tell which to use by setting the `type` attribute in your title-definition files. Default option is Thymeleaf.

Because I am slowly migrating from JSP, the vast majority of the templates are JSPs, so I need to use this `type` attribute, but then I get an error that my title definition file is not valid:

```
org.apache.tiles.definition.DefinitionsFactoryException: XML error reading definitions.
at org.apache.tiles.definition.digester.DigesterDefinitionsReader.read(DigesterDefinitionsReader.java:332)
at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.BaseLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitionsFromURL(BaseLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:276)
at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitionsFromURLs(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:251)
at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitionsFromURLs(ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:65)
at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadParentDefinitions(ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:58)
at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitionsFromURLs(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:239)
at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitionsFromURLs(ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:65)
...
```

This is my tiles definition file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
       "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.1//EN"
       "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_1.dtd">

<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="default" template="/WEB-INF/layouts/default.jspx" type="jsp">
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

If I remove `DOCTYPE` part, I got same error.

Any idea how to get it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `type` attribute only exists in `<put-attribute/>` elements. By contrast, `<definition/>` elements require your attribute to be called `templateType`.

Regards.

Comment: And by the way, this is an error in the project documentation, as it only talks about `type` and does not mention `templateType`. I'll fix asap.